# Write Hyperlink in VBA that Links to Function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a sub that creates a hyperlink to a function for each cell in a column. I keep getting the "reference isn't valid" error message but cannot figure out why. This is an addition to existing code--all the existing code has been working fine in production. All the file paths and sheet names are correct too, and the function works as intended when I run it in the console (Alt+F11, then run through the function line-by-line with F8).

This sub takes a recordset from a SQL query and outputs the results to the worksheet. Then, I try to add a column with a hyperlink to the function below.

```
Sub outputToWs(rsPosDB As ADODB.Recordset, ws As Worksheet, headerRow As Integer)

Dim i As Integer
Dim colCalc As Integer

...

'Loops through recordset and outputs values to worksheet. I deleted most of the code to avoid noise
i = headerRow
While Not (rsPosDB.EOF)
    i = i + 1
        With rsPosDB
            If Left(!ID, 2) <> "AA" Then
                ws.Cells(i, colCalc).FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""#sendToCalc_Click()"", ""Calc"")"
            End If
            ....
        End With
Wend           
...
End Sub
```

The function below is what I'm trying to call from the hyperlink I create in the sub above:

```
Function sendToCalc_Click()
    
    Set sendToCalc_Click = Selection
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
    

    'Copy value in column A to the Calculator workbook    
    Dim calcWB As Workbook
    Set calcWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Calculator v2.xlsm")

    calcWB.Sheets("Calculator").Range("C2") = ws.Cells(Selection.row, 15)
    
End Function
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like opening another workbook is something you can't do in a function called from a hyperlink.  Although no error is raised when calling `Workbooks.open()`, the workbook is not opened and `calcWB` is `Nothing`, so trying to set the cell value raises an error.

```vb
Function sendToCalc_Click()
    
    Dim calcWB As Workbook, c As Range
    
    On Error GoTo haveError
    
    Set c = Selection
    Set calcWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Calculator v2.xlsm")
    Debug.Print "calcWB is nothing?", calcWB Is Nothing
    calcWB.Worksheets("Calculator").Range("C2") = c.EntireRow.Cells(15)
    Debug.Print "Set Cell"
    Set sendToCalc_Click = c
    Exit Function
    
haveError:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Set sendToCalc_Click = c
End Function
```

Output:

```txt
WB is nothing?              True
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

You get the "reference isn't valid" message because the function fails to return a cell reference for the hyperlink to finish its job.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a function to an HLNK but can simulate the call:

```vb
'create some links in cells A1 A2 A3 with reference to themselfs
'Every one will call a function thru Worksheet_FollowHyperlink event
Private Sub createHLNKSexample()
   Dim r As Range, fnames As Variant, c As Long
   fnames = Array("FuncOne", "FuncTwo", "FuncThree")
   Set r = Me.Range("A1:A3")
   For c = 1 To 3
      r(c).Value2 = fnames(c - 1)
      Me.Hyperlinks.Add r(c), "", "'" & Me.Name & "'!" & r(c).Address(0, 0)  '.Offset(0, 1)
   Next
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
   Select Case Target.Parent.Value2
      Case "FuncOne"
         Call MsgBox(FuncOne())
      Case "FuncTwo"
         Call MsgBox(FuncTwo())
      Case "FuncThree"
         Call MsgBox(FuncThree())
   End Select
End Sub

Function FuncOne() As Long
   FuncOne = 1
End Function

Function FuncTwo() As Long
   FuncTwo = 2
End Function

Function FuncThree() As Long
   FuncThree = 3
End Function
```

[image]